# Grafica de series temporales

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, timeseries

Buenas tardes a todos y gracias de antemano.
Cómo podría hacer para graficar la siguiente serie temporal separando según la ID del usuario?
Con dos usuarios es sencillo y se puede hacer de manera manual pero si fueran cosa de 100 ID como podríamos hacerlo codificando?

| ID | Date | Goal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 2020-06-09 19:08:00 | 99.0 |
| ID1 | 2020-06-09 19:23:00 | 92.0 |
| ID1 | 2020-06-09 19:38:00 | 86.0 |
| ID1 | 2020-06-09 19:53:00 | 85.0 |
| ID1 | 2020-06-09 20:08:00 | 85.0 |
| ID1 | 2020-06-09 20:23:00 | 87.0 |
| ID1 | 2020-06-09 20:38:00 | 88.0 |
| ID1 | 2020-06-09 20:53:00 | 93.0 |
| ID1 | 2020-06-09 21:08:00 | 106.0 |
| ID2 | 2020-06-10 00:54:00 | 100.0 |
| ID2 | 2020-06-10 01:09:00 | 101.0 |
| ID2 | 2020-06-10 01:24:00 | 106.0 |
| ID2 | 2020-06-10 01:39:00 | 113.0 |
| ID2 | 2020-06-10 01:54:00 | 116.0 |
| ID2 | 2020-06-10 02:09:00 | 113.0 |
| ID2 | 2020-06-10 02:24:00 | 113.0 |
| ID2 | 2020-06-10 02:39:00 | 112.0 |
| ID2 | 2020-06-10 02:54:00 | 110.0 |
| ID2 | 2020-06-10 03:09:00 | 110.0 |
| ID2 | 2020-06-10 03:24:00 | 107.0 |

Muchas gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Quizás la forma más simple sea usar seaborn, que te permite pintar en una misma gráfica diferentes conjuntos de datos. En este caso se usaría `hue="ID"` para que a cada ID le asigne un color (y una línea) diferente.

Puedes representar todo en la misma gráfica, usando `lineplot`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.lineplot(data=df, x="Date", y="Goal", hue="ID")
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

El resultado se ve así:

[image: Resultado]

donde como ves, a cada ID le ha asignado una línea y un color diferente, y te ha generado automáticamente una leyenda. El problema en este caso es que la timeseries de ID2 comienza un día diferente de la de ID1, por lo que no se ven las gráficas en paralelo, sino seguidas. No sé si es esto lo que esperabas, pero en realidad depende de tus datos.

Seaborn también te permite crear una gráfica separada para cada ID y poner una debajo de otra, por ejemplo. Esto se puede lograr así:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.relplot(data=df,  kind="line", x="Date", y="Goal", row="ID", height=2, aspect=3)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

siendo el resultado ahora

[image: Resultado]

En este caso cada gráfica tiene su propio eje de tiempos, si bien sólo se muestra en las etiquetas los correspondientes a la gráfica inferior.

También podrías procesar tu dataframe para añadirle un campo "Hora" que saque la hora del campo "Date", y usar entonces `x="Hora"` al momento de hacer el plot, y así la gráfica mostraría la variación según la hora, sin importar el día, por lo que el `lineplot()` del inicio lo mostraría todo "junto", de forma que es más fácil comparar cada ID.

### Ampliación

Habrás visto que la forma en la que se muestran las etiquetas del eje X no es muy agradable visualmente. He tenido que rotarlas 90º para evitar que aparecieran todas pegadas entre sí, por contener un texto muy largo. Ello se debe a que (al menos en el dataframe que estoy usando de ejemplo) la columna Date es de tipo cadena. La cosa mejora si se le hace una conversión al tipo `datetime`:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

Ahora seaborn ya es capaz de procesar correctamente este dato para mostrar unas etiquetas más cortas y mejor repartidas por el eje x:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3))
sns.lineplot(data=df, x="Date", y="Goal", hue="ID")
```

[image: Resultado]

Además, como puedes ver, ahora la escala temporal es más correcta, dejando incluso el hueco de 4h entre las 21:00 de un día y las 01:00 del día siguiente (pues para esas horas no hay datos).

Comment: Muchas gracias!